# Does Punishing Eye count as an attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, artificer

The last time I played my Artificer I used Punishing Eye and Spike Wire on a boss and waited for my ally's attack.

First, my ally's attack got my Wis modifier for an attack, then the Eye triggered and applied my Int modifier and Wis modifier to the boss as damage after the attack. (3 + 5 + 3 = 11 damage.)

We've been arguing about this ever since because the other players don't accept that Punishing Eye is an attack. Is it?

Answer (score 6):

No. Punishing eye is not an attack.

An Attack has a target line. Punishing eye *only* has the Effect line.